# Creating new model instance with paramethers (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, post, routes, parameters

I need to create new Event from User's guest page and the Event.visitor_id should be User.id

Event.rb

```
def create
@event = current_user.owner_events.new(event_params)
end

protected

def event_params
params.require(:event).permit(:visitor_id)
end
```

I need to correct the view below which is not working:

```
<%= link_to "Create event with this user", events_path(visitor_id: @user.id), method: :post %>
```

I get: ActionController::ParameterMissing in EventsController#create

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try that (you forgot to add `event` key):

```
<%= link_to "Create event with this user", events_path(event: { visitor_id: @user.id }), method: :post %>
```

For more details read ['strong parameters' gem documentation](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters).

Comment: This doesn't work as well but thank you for the link.

Answer (score 0):

I just had to add .to_i to @user.id

```
<%= link_to "Create event", events_path(:event =>{:visitor_id => @user.id.to_i} ), :method => :post %>
```

Comment: Really? It's unlikely to be true. Could you plz delete `to_i` and recheck it? I'm sure it was because of absence of `event` key.